# How to get a sprite rect in a convenient way?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d game development, **CGRectContainsPoint** method often used to detect if touch on a  CCSprite.

I use code fllow to get a sprite's (which in a CCNode) rect property

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEnded");
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    CCLOG(@"location.x:%f, y:%f", location.x, location.y);
    CGRect rect;

    rect = CGRectMake(self.firstCard.face.position.x-(self.firstCard.face.contentSize.width/2), self.firstCard.face.position.y-(self.firstCard.face.contentSize.height/2),
                      self.firstCard.face.contentSize.width, self.firstCard.face.contentSize.height);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
        CCLOG(@"first card touched");
        [firstCard open];
    }

    rect = CGRectMake(self.secondCard.face.position.x-(self.secondCard.face.contentSize.width/2), self.secondCard.face.position.y-(self.secondCard.face.contentSize.height/2),
                      self.secondCard.face.contentSize.width, self.secondCard.face.contentSize.height);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
        CCLOG(@"second card touched");
        [secondCard open];
    }


}
```

I want to know if there is a convenient way to **get a CCSprite 's rect** straightforward?

Comment: You can get the sprite rect by [sprite_nm boundingBox]; method. I think it would work for you. It returns the whole Rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use boundingBox i think it will be a great option to use.

Like this:

```
- ( void ) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   locationTouchBegan = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    //location is The Point Where The User Touched

    locationTouchBegan = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:locationTouchBegan];

    //Detect the Touch On sprite

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], locationTouchBegan))
    {
        isSpriteTouched=YES;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kobold2D has a convenience method [containsPoint](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/Kobold2D/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/cocos2d-ext/CCNodeExtensions.m#L38) as a CCNode extension (Objective-C category) which you can replicate in your project:

```
-(BOOL) containsPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect bbox = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize_.width, contentSize_.height);
    CGPoint locationInNodeSpace = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(bbox, locationInNodeSpace);
}
```

Your code then be simplified to this and it will work with rotated and/or scaled sprites as well (the boundingBox method fails to test rotated and scaled sprites correctly).

```
if ([firstCard.face containsPoint:location]) {
        CCLOG(@"first card touched");
}
```